# CSS for "fill parent width?"

Tags: css

I have an item on the DOM that I'd simply like to have fill its parent's width, regardless of what that is:

```
<div width="800">
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

How can I specify in CSS that the `filler` class match the width of its parent?

```
.filler {
    ?
}
```

Comment: By default a block level element (eg `div`) will fill it's parent... you can specify `width:100%;` too if you want, although that's the default, and will cause issues if you have padding/margin/borders in some browsers ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make CSS width to fill parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232440/how-to-make-css-width-to-fill-parent)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Have you tried: `width: 100%;` ?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that `a`'s width should be 100% of the actual browser? When I've done it in the past, I'm pretty sure that's what the outcome has been.

Comment: @TK No, unless absolute positioning is specified, the dimensions are relative to the parent element.

Comment: What about the height?? In my case the inner element is an `a` (idk if that makes a difference), but `height:100%;` did not do the trick.

Comment: Just realized the question was specifically about the width. My bad.

Answer (score 51):

Depending on what you inner item is, there are various approaches.

If it's a block-level element (a paragraph, a div, etc.), it will automatically adjust itself to fill 100% of the container's width.

If it's an inline element, too bad for you, it won't accept `width:100%` until you convert it to a block-level element: `display:block`.

Floated elements are a special case: they will only span to the width of their inner content, even if they're block level elements. They require `width:100%`.

Absolutely positioned elements are even tougher: they need `width:100%`, but the container also needs a positioning context, eg. `position:relative`.

Examples of all four cases: http://jsfiddle.net/dD7E4/

Comment: it's possible to assign `width:100%` to inline elements such as span or inline-block.

Comment: @Magne, I beg to differ. Inline-block will happily accept `width:100%` due to its block-like nature, but a barebones, unstyled `span` will not.

Comment: you might be right about the `span`. I haven't tested that. But both inline-block and span are treated as inline elements outside, so I assumed that the behaviour would be the same..

Comment: It is not. An unstyled `span` has `display:inline` and its width cannot be set. If it's styled with `dipsplay:inline-block`, it starts sharing the properties of both displays: it appears in the document flow similarly to an inline element, but its dimensions can be forced just as if it was a block element.

Answer (score 6):

If the inner element is not a div and has padding or margin, flexbox might be the best solution:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.filler {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See also [this answer about how to fill remaining vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445860/6723250).

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's something stopping them, block-level elements such as `div` and `p` will always fill the entire width of their container. If you have an inline element such as a `span` or an `a`, you could style it as `display: block` to turn it into a block-level element, but this will also put a line break before and after it.

Answer (score 1):

div is a block element and by default fill his parent.
if it doesn't you probably use `float:left` or `float:right` or `display:inline` or your parent is not 800px.
(maybe you should try with `style="width:800px"` or `width="800px"` instead of `width="800"`)
I usually put a color border to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

By default it will fill its parent element's width as div is an block element.