# Fill remaining vertical space - only CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to fill the **remaining vertical space** of `#wrapper` under `#first` with `#second` div.

I need an only CSS solution.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

#first {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #F5DEB3;
}

#second {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #9ACD32;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete No, they are dynamic. Only first div is of fixed 200px height. while second div will fill the remaining height of wrapper

Comment: Do you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/K5n4U/

Comment: @laaposto no this isn't the thing. Wrapper should be 100% filling the entire vertical height of the screen.

Comment: this is a better example : https://codepen.io/micjamking/pen/QdojLz

Comment: A nice and neat overview of some  common solutions for this problem (quite an obvious issue in my opinion, I find it very surprising that there is not a clear, definitive css solution)
https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/css/how-to-make-a-div-take-the-remaining-height

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this with `position:absolute;` on the `#second` div like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Cb5bu/)**

*CSS :*

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

#second {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#9ACD32;
}
```

**EDIT : Alternative solution**

Depending on your layout and the content you have in those divs, you could make it much more simple and with less markup like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9TvM6/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#9ACD32;
}
#first {
    background-color:#F5DEB3;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Not, it is not filling the remaining space of wrapper. If you suppose decrease the height of wrapper you can see that it is not filling it.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow just add `position:relative;` to `#wrapper` like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Cb5bu/ and the div will fill the remaining space of wrapper.

Comment: Excellent Work. Thanks Dear Web-Tiki

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow - I should point out that if you have too much content in this olution, the overflow won't be handled well: http://jsfiddle.net/Cb5bu/7/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/3EjX8/2/

Comment: @JimmyRare and why is that you don't see it as a flexible solution? will it make any problem?

Comment: @Pete Well the point here is to fill the remaining space because it lacks content... If it had to much content, there would not be any problem.

Comment: @Pete, I see that you are correct when it overflows with content. But fortunately, due to some limited content it will not be overflowed.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow No worries, was just pointing out in case it did

Comment: Hey! Web-Tiki! your example really helped in many other problems. I got a sound understanding how to deal with such CSS issues. Thanks again.

Comment: For future readers who want to do this but don't know the height of #first you can use the display:flex css solution specified below which causes #second to expand to all remaining space even if #first's height changes.

Comment: Not working when you add some content. It does not stay inside the block.

Comment: I think this is not a working solution to the question. If the height of `#first` changes, `#second` does not change, and thus it does _not_ fill the remaining vertical space (see the first fiddle of the answer)

Answer (score 65):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.first {
  height: 50px;
}

.second {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first" style="background:#b2efd8">First</div>
  <div class="second" style="background:#80c7cd">Second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution provides so much ease. Ty

Comment: There is a vertical scroll in the rendered example, so it's slightly bigger vertically.

Answer (score 57):

You can use CSS Flexbox instead another display value, The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their size is unknown and/or dynamic.

**Example**

```
/* CONTAINER */
#wrapper
{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* SOME ITEM CHILD ELEMENTS */
#first
{
   width:300px;
    height: 200px;
   background-color:#F5DEB3;

}

#second
{
   width:300px;
   background-color: #9ACD32;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: 1; /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1; /* NEW, */
}
```

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5nsv8/)

If you want to have full support for old browsers like IE9 or below, you will have to use a polyfills like [flexy](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie), this polyfill enable support for Flexbox model but only for 2012 spec of flexbox model.

Recently I found another polyfill to help you with Internet Explorer 8 & 9 or any older browser that not have support for flexbox model, I still have not tried it but I leave the link [here](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility)

You can find a usefull and [complete Guide to Flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by Chris Coyer [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Flexbox model is only supported on higher version of IE10. If you can partial support for older versions of IE you need to use polyfill like flexie

Comment: Will it work on IE10? caniuse.com suggests no, and unfortunately I have to support it for a little while longer. (Turns out the correct answer is 'sort of': https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If anyone is reading this and wants to make the wrapper div fill the height of the entire page, then simply change height: 300px; to height:100vh;

Answer (score 12):

If you can add an extra couple of divs so your html looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first" class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can make use of the `display:table` properties:

```
#wrapper
{
   width:300px;
   height:100%;
   display:table;
}

.row 
{
   display:table-row;
}

.cell 
{
   display:table-cell;
}

#first .cell
{
   height:200px;
   background-color:#F5DEB3;
}

#second .cell
{
   background-color:#9ACD32;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3EjX8/)

Comment: Exactly this, but is it cross-browser?

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow it should work in all browsers from ie8 - http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: Finally a dinamic answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the wrapper height to vh instead of %?

```
#wrapper {
width:300px;
height:100vh;
}
```

That worked great for me when I wanted to fill my page with a gradient background for instance...

Comment: The easiest, and most effective answer here. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have fix heights for your main-container (top, bottom, ....), you can simply use this [css-file](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/5.0/framework/indigo-5.0.css) to get a flex-container which uses the remaining space incl. working!!! scrollbars

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ym37e3sz/3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Flex Container</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.qooxdoo.org/5.0/framework/indigo-5.0.css">

  <style>
    .cont{
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .headerContainer {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mainContainer {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll
    }

    .footerContainer {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }
  </style>


  </head>

<body class="qx-flex-ready" style="height: 100%">
  <div class="qx-vbox cont">
    <div class="headerContainer">Cell 1: flex1</div>
    <div class="mainContainer qx-flex3">
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>

    </div>
    <div class="footerContainer" >Cell 3: flex1</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is a bit of improved markup. Wrap the second within the first and it will render under.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
        Here comes the first content
        <div id="second">I will render below the first content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ETNU/2/)

Comment: Not working, can you make it with Some colors and boxes?

Comment: Jimmy wrapper is just actually hiding the overflowed content, second div is not filling remaining space. you can see by putting some more content inside it

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood. The `#first` div has a fixed height? Not dynamic?

Comment: Yes, JimmyRare It's fixed

Comment: this is probably what you were looking for @JimmyRare :http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9ETNU/3/ no?

Comment: @web-tiki Not really, I think? :D
It becomes a mess with 100% height on html/body when you start scrolling content.

Comment: that is just for the demo so it shows it is responsive height but you can do it like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9ETNU/5/

Answer (score -3):

You can just add the **overflow:auto** option:

```
#second
{
   width:300px;
   height:100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color:#9ACD32;
}
```