# Make div fit remaining height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have the following divs

```
<div class="top">
   <div class="inner1"></div>
   <div class="inner2"></div>
   <div class="inner3"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.top { 
    height: 100vh;
}

.div1 {
    min-height: 215px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30vh;
}

.div2 { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 30vh - 265px);
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: table;
}

.div3 {
    min-height: 265px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: white;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
}
```

I don't want to use calc(100vh - 30vh - 265px) to set the min-height of div 2. How can I have it so that it takes the remaining height (meaning div2 height = 100vh - div1 height - div2 height.

I'm guessing flex could be useful here, but I'm not quite sure how to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks?

Before marking this as a duplicate, please note: I tried using flex and it doesn't work well in IE11.

Comment: It should work fine in IE11. Can you post an example? The only problem would be IE10 where you would have to use -ms- prefix.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486 if you are willing to use flex

Comment: Flexbox works fine in IE11....

Comment: Please [don't duplicate your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874066/div-takes-remaining-height) - if your question is closed as a dup, asking it again by copy+paste is not a good way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best idea, but to overcome cross browser limitations, I usually use javascript to recalculate that. I write javascript function and then fire it on window resize and on load.

```js
// some jQuery
function adjustHeight() {
var fullHeight = $(window).height();

var neededHeight = fullHeight - fullHeight*0.3 - 263;

$('.div2').css('min-height', neededHeight + 'px');

}


$(document).ready(function(){ adjustHeight(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

beside flex, display:table properties could help as well for older browser.

**in this case height turns to be min-height**

```css
.top {
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.top>div {
  display: table-row;
}
.inner1 {
  min-height: 215px;/* becomes useless */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30vh;
  background: tomato;
}
.inner2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 2.5em;/* i'll get squeezed here */
  margin-top: 0;/* useless, border-spacing is to be used */
  background: turquoise;
}
.inner3 {
  height: 265px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 42px;/* ? :) */
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="inner1">1</div>
  <div class="inner2">run me in full page to see how i behave :)</div>
  <div class="inner3">3</div>
</div>
```