# How can I set "fill_parent" value as an element's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I have to say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330895/css-for-fill-parent) seems an identical question with mine. But it isn't.

I have this HTML:

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 70%;
}

.title{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.input {
  /* width: fill_parent; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="title">title: </span>
  <input class="input" name="title" type="text" placeholder="عنوان دقیقی انتخاب کنید">
</div>
```

All I need is setting a value which means something like `fill_parent` as that input's `width`. As you see, the width of that `.parent` is based on percentage, so it will be changed when the size of screen changes. That's why I cannot use a value based on `px` as `.input`'s `width`.

**Note:** `.input{width: 100%;}` isn't what I'm looking for, because I need to keep both the title and input in the same line.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Bootstrap has some good functionality for this, take a look at their column system, otherwise you cant do much better then going 20% on the title and 80% on the input or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `display:flex;` on your parent and then `flex:1;` on your input.

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 70%;
  display:flex;
}

.title{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.input {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="title">title: </span>
  <input class="input" name="title" type="text" placeholder="عنوان دقیقی انتخاب کنید">
</div>
```