# Div inside another div incorrectly takes parent div width

Tags: html, layout, css

Here is your dumb HTML/CSS question for the day....

I have a div that contains two other divs. The container is set to display: box/-webkit-box/etc to stack the contained divs horizontally. The first contained div is some fixed content, and the second contains a bunch of other little tile divs.

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/T2EZy/3/

Also a cheesy diagram (please note the **1000px shown is only an example** -- there is no width set on any of the div containers):

[image: Cheesy diagram]

My problem is the second contained div takes the width of the parent, so it's always stretching outside the browser. I want the two divs to be contained inside the container. Everything needs to be dynamic so when the browser resizes the content adjusts correctly. I can't put a fixed size on the container or the second div.

Comment: Do you have to use display: box? Can you go with the older float method? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gpdV3/)

Comment: @GeoffWarren: Thanks! display: box isn't required. Frankly floats are bizarre/magic to me and I seldom get them to work. I played with something like that before but couldn't quite get it to happen, but your example has it working perfectly. If you post this as a question I"ll mark it as an answer.

Comment: I modified my original answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not required to use display: box, try using the older float method: http://jsfiddle.net/gpdV3/

Answer (score 0):

if you know the parent with in PX not in 100% .

let's say how you put in you screenshot "1000px" your css is going to work

ex:

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/T2EZy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the parent and children size its really easy. http://jsfiddle.net/rTL6T/

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you are forcing by code the width of your div (something like .MyClass{width:1000px}).

Please take a look at this answer:

[How to make CSS width to fill parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232440/css-width-to-fill-parent)