# Is It Possible To Have A Div With White Space No Wrap And 100% Width of Parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div within a parent that does horizontal scrolling. I have css and jquery that makes it possible to do such, but I had to use white space no wrap to get the content to overflow horizontally. That all works fine if I define a set width for said div say 55rem for instance. But my website is responsive, I can't adjust the width to every dimension... so I would like to use 100% width, but that overflows no matter what I tried.

I've looked around to see if I could find anything specifically talking about this, and I couldn't even find anything telling me it isn't possible for some reason. Maybe I didn't use the right keywords, I'm not sure.

For argument's sake, here is the grandparent.

```
.dashboard_container {
display: table;
height: 100%;
width: 55rem;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

Here is my parent.

```
.dashboard_post_container {
background: white;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
-webkit-border-radius: .4rem;
-moz-border-radius: .4rem;
border-radius: .4rem;
margin-bottom: 2rem;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the child.

```
.dashboard_suggestions {
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Someone commented requesting an example so here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08vwyg4b/

You just need to change the child's width to 100% to see what I mean.

I want the child to be 100% width of the parent and grandparent... essentially. But I must use white space no-wrap to accomplish the main goal of what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to know which elements you're trying to target / exclude. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's familiar ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232440/how-to-make-css-width-to-fill-parent))

Just change **display**(to block) and **width** attribute

```css
.dashboard_container {
    display: block;
    width: 50%; /*Resize for test responsive*/
    /*Your css*/
    }
.dashboard_post_container {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    /*Your css*/
    }
.dashboard_suggestions {
    width: auto;
    /*Your css*/

    }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/569v7oyr/)